# Unable to detect database type

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying to create a Spring Boot application using [sqljdbc4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4) driver with this config:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:sqlserver://dbhost:1433;databaseName=test"
    username: dbuser
    password: dbuser
    tomcat:
      test-on-borrow: true
      validation-query: select 1
```

But, when I run, I get this error: `Unable to detect database type`

I was debugging `BatchDatabaseInitializer`, where error came from, and when it calls `JdbcUtils.commonDatabaseName(...)`, "Microsoft SQL Server" is returned as product name that doesn't match with any DatabaseDriver's product name.

I tried other drivers but they all have the same problem.

Is it a bug?

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.1-RELEASE.

Comment: What is the product name you're getting back?

Comment: @MichaelMinella Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: I meant from the driver.

Comment: SQLServerDatabaseMetadata.getDatabaseProductName() is returning "Microsoft SQL Server".

Answer (score 4):

You need to properly configure your spring.datasource config in application.properties file if you're using spring-batch to create batch jobs. Below is mine ->

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/batch_repo
spring.datasource.username=batch_username
spring.datasource.password=batch_password
spring.datasource.platform=mysql

spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
```

***spring.batch.initialize-schema*** when configured to "**always**", will create the necessary spring batch related tables in your schema.

Alternatively, if you assign it to "**never**", it will refrain from creating the tables. In both these cases your error should get resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your Application file within the `main` function.

```
@SpringBootApplication(
        exclude = {
                BatchAutoConfiguration.class,
                JmxAutoConfiguration.class
        },
        excludeName = {
                "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration",
        }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=never` in props file. It worked for me in spring-boot v2.6.x

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in my unit tests after updating spring to 2.7. I added this to solve the problem:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your application.properties.
spring.batch.schema=classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-sqlserver.sql

Answer (score 0):

Check your application.properties file like below.

Note: springbatch is my DB name

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springbatch
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Vishal@123
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).