# How creating bean with name 'quartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer'

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz

I try to use quartz , in first time to run mi API every days so i following this example
[Scheduling in Spring with Quartz](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule)
and i have chose Quartz and and JDBC jobStore but i can't run my application, i'm not sure this useful at this step i use MariaDB.
And in my application.properties i have éclipse error The word 'jdbc' is not correctly spelled

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-06-22 11:00:33.923 ERROR 27332 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/quartz/QuartzAutoConfiguration$JdbcStoreTypeConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.quartz.QuartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer]: Factory method 'quartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at com.myp.BatchListDomApplication.main(BatchListeBlancheApplication.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.quartz.QuartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer]: Factory method 'quartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.determinePlatform(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:132) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.lambda$resolveAll$0(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:96) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.resolveAll(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:121) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.resolveAll(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:96) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.quartz.QuartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.resolveSchemaLocations(QuartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:105) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.quartz.QuartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.getSettings(QuartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:89) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.quartz.QuartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.<init>(QuartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:51) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.quartz.QuartzAutoConfiguration$JdbcStoreTypeConfiguration.quartzDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer(QuartzAutoConfiguration.java:143) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/listeBlanche?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.jpa.database = MYSQL
server.port=8089
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.batch.initialize-schema=never


org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=2
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread=true
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=quartzDataSource
# change value dataSource
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.URL=jdbc:h2:mem:spring-quartz;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_h2.sql'
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.driver=org.h2.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.user=root
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.password=root
org.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=never
```

I try to change and remove org.quartz.dataSource and spring shema but same error

Pom.xml

```xml
<properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.6</org.projectlombok.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I try to include 3 file from the example
[Depot git spring-quartz](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-quartz)
end  i only change some import and spéciale job using  my web services
[QrtzScheduler.java](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-quartz/src/main/java/org/baeldung/springquartz/basics/scheduler/QrtzScheduler.java),[SampleJob.java](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-quartz/src/main/java/org/baeldung/springquartz/basics/scheduler/SampleJob.java) change for call my api, [AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory.java](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-quartz/src/main/java/org/baeldung/springquartz/config/AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory.java) exactly the same

```java
package com.mypackage.hexa.infrastructure.domain;

import com.mypackage.hexa.domain.UpdateListeBlancheJob;
import com.mypackage.hexa.infrastructure.domain.AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory;
import org.quartz file.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob;
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:quartz.properties")
public class QrtzScheduler {}
```

I change `propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"));` to `application.properties` and change org.quartz to spring.quartz and now my application start call my job,
But I have nothing in my Quartz database.

Comment: In our product design we use JDBC job store when running app in a cluster, but for other purpose a RAM job store should be ok. Also there error seems to with connecting to DB , check this out :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42073194/unable-to-detect-database-type

Comment: i add my application and quartz porteries

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/wiki/How-to-Setup-Databases

Comment: Look at this example: https://github.com/hawk1234/spring-quartz-example

Comment: it's a conflict with spring-boot-starter-quartz , I managed to start my applcation but it doesn't call my job

Answer (score 0):

```java
 @Bean
    public Scheduler scheduler(Trigger trigger, JobDetail job, SchedulerFactoryBean factory) throws SchedulerException {
        log.debug("Getting a handle to the Scheduler");
        Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
        if (scheduler.checkExists(job.getKey())){
            scheduler.deleteJob(job.getKey());
        }
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

        log.debug("Starting Scheduler threads");
        scheduler.start();
        return scheduler;
    }
```

```
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
org.quartz.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=2
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=quartzDataSource
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=qrtz_
# change value dataSource
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.URL=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/quartzData
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.driver=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.user=root
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.password=root
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.provider=hikaricp
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export=true
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.registryHost=localhost
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.registryPort=1099
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.createRegistry=true
```

Comment: Is this an answer or question post complement?